# Aggregating based on "near" row values

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, na

I have a very messy dataframe (webscraped) that unfortunately has many double and even triple entries in it. Most of the dataframe looks like this:

```
> df1<-data.frame(var1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d"),var2=c("right.a",NA,"right.b",NA,"right.c",NA,"right.d",NA),var3=c("correct.a","correct.a","correct.b","correct.b","correct.c","correct.c","correct.d","correct.d"))
> df1
  var1    var2      var3
1    a right.a correct.a
2    a    <NA> correct.a
3    b right.b correct.b
4    b    <NA> correct.b
5    c right.c correct.c
6    c    <NA> correct.c
7    d right.d correct.d
8    d    <NA> correct.d
```

"var1"  is my ID variable that I need to use to aggregate. My goal is to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  var1    var2      var3
1    a right.a correct.a
2    b right.b correct.b
3    c right.c correct.c
4    d right.d correct.d
```

However, the main problem is, that not the whole dataframe looks like this. In fact, I have other parts that look like this:

```
> df2<-data.frame(var1=c("e","e","e","f","f","g","g","g"),var2=c(NA,NA,"right.e",NA,NA,NA,"right.g",NA),var3=c("correct.e","correct.e",NA,"correct.f",NA,"correct.g","correct.g",NA))
> df2
  var1    var2      var3
1    e    <NA> correct.e
2    e    <NA> correct.e
3    e right.e      <NA>
4    f    <NA> correct.f
5    f    <NA>      <NA>
6    g    <NA> correct.g
7    g right.g   wrong.g
8    g    <NA>      <NA>
```

And other variations. In the end, every ID should have one row with the correct and right var2 and var3 in it. At this point, I get lost: My var1 is **not unique**. However, I know that duplicate IDs that "belong" together are grouped in the dataframe (as seen in my examples); e.g. there might be another "a" in row 4102 and 4103.

What I think would be the way to go is using aggregate with var1 as ID,but in addition telling R that aggregate should just check +-2 rows of var1 when doing so. Any ideas how to code this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(var2[!is.na(var2)][1], var3[!is.na(var3)][1]), by=var1]
   var1      V1        V2
1:    a right.a correct.a
2:    b right.b correct.b
3:    c right.c correct.c
4:    d right.d correct.d
```

and

```
setDT(df2)[, .(var2[!is.na(var2)][1], var3[!is.na(var3)][1]), by=var1]
   var1      V1        V2
1:    e right.e correct.e
2:    f      NA correct.f
3:    g right.g correct.g
```

The idea in `var2[!is.na(var2)][1]` for example, to take the first non-missing value from var2. If all values are missing, then this returns NA. This operation is performed for both variables by var1.

If you have more than two variables, you might switch to `lapply`. For example, the following.

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(i) i[!is.na(i)][1]), by=var1]
   var1    var2      var3
1:    a right.a correct.a
2:    b right.b correct.b
3:    c right.c correct.c
4:    d right.d correct.d
```

In an instance where more than one var1 has a valid value, and this is indicated by a non-missing var2, then you can reach the intended result with a join.

The data from the comment,

```
df1<-data.frame(var1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","a","a"),
                var2=c("right.a",NA,"right.b",NA,"right.c",NA,"right.d",NA,"right.a1",NA),
                var3=c("correct.a","correct.a","correct.b","correct.b","correct.c","correct.c","correct.d","correct.d","correct.a1","correct.a1"))
```

Then, with this data,

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .(var2=var2[!is.na(var2)]), by=var1], on=.(var1, var2)]
   var1     var2       var3
1:    a  right.a  correct.a
2:    a right.a1 correct.a1
3:    b  right.b  correct.b
4:    c  right.c  correct.c
5:    d  right.d  correct.d
```

Here, all non-missing var2 observations by var1 are merged onto the original data set.

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks promising. Any idea on how to deal with the duplicates in the dataframe (i.e. observations with the same ID grouped at random positions in the dataframe)? If df1 looks like this: `df1<-data.frame(var1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","a","a"),var2=c("right.a",NA,"right.b",NA,"right.c",NA,"right.d",NA,"right.a1",NA),var3=c("correct.a","correct.a","correct.b","correct.b","correct.c","correct.c","correct.d","correct.d","correct.a1","correct.a1"))` the code unfortunately just takes the first "a" and not the second.

Comment: See the additional text at the end of the answer.

Comment: Your last line of code including the join throws me this error: `Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df1), df1[, .(var2 = var2[!is.na(var2)]),  : 
  'on' argument should be a named atomic vector oc column names indicating which columns in 'i' should be joined with which columns in 'x'.`

Comment: Just tried it again with a fresh session of R and it worked. You probably have to update the version of `data.table` you are using. I'm using 1.10.4. If that is not an option, you might try replacing `on=.(var1, var2)` with `on=c("var1", "var2")`.

Answer (score 1):

If `var2` and `var3` have only one unique value for each level of `var1`, then:

```
library(dplyr)

df = rbind(df1,df2)

df %>% group_by(var1) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

> ```
>    var1    var2      var3
> 1     a right.a correct.a
> 2     b right.b correct.b
> 3     c right.c correct.c
> 4     d right.d correct.d
> 5     e right.e correct.e
> 6     f    <NA> correct.f
> 7     g right.g correct.g
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this takes the "right.g" into the f-row (as there is no "right.f" in my dataset).

Comment: Turns out the problem was related to a [column type issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1463) when all values in a group are `NA` (as is the case for `var2` here when `var1=="f"`). I've fixed it by using `NA_character_` instead of `NA`.

Comment: Updated to adapt @Imo's shorter code for dealing with groups that are all `NA`.