# na.locf using group_by from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I'm trying to use `na.locf` from package `zoo` with grouped data using `dplyr`. I'm using the first solution on this question: [Using dplyr window-functions to make trailing values (fill in NA values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/using-dplyr-window-functions-to-make-trailing-values-fill-in-na-values)

```
library(dplyr);library(zoo)
df1 <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A","B"),each=3),problem=c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA),ok=c(NA,3,4,5,6,NA))
df1
  id problem ok
1  A       1 NA
2  A      NA  3
3  A       2  4
4  B      NA  5
5  B      NA  6
6  B      NA NA
```

The problem happens when, within a group, all the data is NA. As you can see in the problem column, the `na.locf` data for id=B comes from another group: the last data of id=A.

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% na.locf()

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: id [2]

     id problem    ok
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1     A       1  <NA>
2     A       1     3
3     A       2     4
4     B       2     5 #problem col is wrong
5     B       2     6 #problem col is wrong
6     B       2     6 #problem col is wrong
```

This is my expected result. The data for id=B is independent of what is in id=A

```
     id problem    ok
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1     A       1  <NA>
2     A       1     3
3     A       2     4
4     B       NA     5
5     B       NA     6
6     B       NA     6
```

Comment: This looks like something similar to the [bug desribed here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1463). I got caught by this in [a recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43100751/496488) (you need to look at a previous version  of the answer, as I later edited it to fix).

Comment: Yeah, it might be a bug. I'm just glad there's a workaround with `mutate_all` as per @Akrun's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to use `na.locf` within `mutate_all` as `na.locf` can be applied directly on the dataset.  Eventhough it is grouped by 'id', applying `na.locf` by applying on the full dataset is not following any group by behavior

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate_all(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE)))
#    id problem    ok
#  <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1      A       1    NA
#2      A       1     3
#3      A       2     4
#4      B      NA     5
#5      B      NA     6
#6      B      NA     6
```

Comment: any idea why it's not applying the group by behavior?

Comment: @bjoseph  It is applying the group by behavior.  If we look at the 'problem', it is already all NAs for 'b' 'id'